# Die kleine Raupe Nimmersatt

Tags: translation, word-order

There is a children’s story called *Die kleine Raupe Nimmersatt.* I know that this is translated from *[The Very Hungry Caterpillar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Very_Hungry_Caterpillar).*

But trying to retranslate this directly, *Die kleine Raupe Nimmersatt* becomes *The little caterpillar Hungry.*

- Why is there a change in word order?
- How does *kleine* mean *very?*
- Why is it not *Die sehr nimmersatte Raupe?*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I think your edit went a bit too far. We do not know from the original question whether the OP knew which title was the original one. And it renders the start of my answer invalid, what (AFAIK) an edit shouldn't normally do.

Comment: @Matthias: While I admit that it is a borderline case, I disagree. The core of the question remains is not about the direction of translation. The first paragraph of your answer would ideally have been a comment on the question (not that it’s a big issue).

Comment: Did Eric Carle translate it himself, by the way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be precise, "Die kleine Raupe Nimmersatt" doesn't *translate to* "The very hungry caterpillar". The English title is the original one, and the German one is a translation.

I'd say the translator allowed himself a certain degree of freedom, as it is common in literature. "Nimmersatt" is a nice word to express "very hungry" very concisely. In fact, it goes beyond "*very* hungry" and says "never satisfied", that is *always* hungry. The effect is augmented by using it as a name and not a simple adjective. As such, it has to come after "Raupe". "Die Raupe Nimmersatt", however, might sound a bit incomplete. By introducing "kleine", which has no direct equivalent in the English version, the translator could round it up and also match the rhythm of the original title.

Of course, most of this is interpretation. You'd need to ask the translator (or the publisher?) for a definite answer to "why?".

Comment: The "klein" may also have been inserted to emphasize it's about cute little beings, a book for children. The same is occasionally done, e.g. "The Hobbit" becomes "Der kleine Hobbit" in some versions.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's true. And maybe he was happy with all reasons together. I think the same applies for giving the creature a name, which IMHO makes the title sound a bit more like a children's book.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the title was changed for purely poetic reasons.
The original English title has a regular meter (unstressed, stressed,
unstressed, stressed, ...), but the literal translation into
German "Die sehr hungrige Raupe" does not. By choosing the
less literal translation "Die kleine Raupe Nimmersatt" (i.e,
"the little caterpillar *Always-Hungry*"), it was possible to
preserve the original meter. It just sounds nicer, that's probably
the entire reason.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is in the word *Nimmersatt*, which translates to "always hungry"; but in this case is also the name of the caterpillar.

*Klein*, of course, means *small* and is the adjective to *Raupe*. The German title doesn't use or need the *very*, because that's implicitly in the name of *Nimmersatt*.

Your translation "The little caterpillar Hungry" is literally correct. It could be extended to "The little caterpillar Alwaysveryhungry" to be even more close to the meaning of the German, but that is no longer really English.

Comment: It translates rather to "never full" as suggested by [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/Nimmersatt.html). Otherwise, it would be "Raupe ImmerHungrig".

Comment: @Em1: Ok, agree, but that is probably even less understandable in English.